# "object reference not set to an instance of an object" while creating the authorization of the staff to use the application

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create the code as below and error saying "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
Public Shared Function bGetStaffCode(ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal conn As SqlConnection, ByRef strErr As String) As Boolean
    ' TODO: NotImplemented statement: ICSharpCode.SharpRefactory.Parser.AST.VB.OnErrorStatement
    Try

        'Dim bStaffCode As Boolean
        Dim strSQL As String = "select count(*) from portal_BillFinderAccess  where loginID = 'Elvis Tan '"

        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = strSQL

        'If CInt(myCommand.ExecuteScalar) = 0 Then

        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
        Dim myDS As New DataSet
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "count")
        If myDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString = "0" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are not authorized to use this application!")
            Return False
        Else
            Return True

        End If

    Catch err As Configuration.ConfigurationException
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
    Finally
    End Try


End Function`
```

Comment: which line does the error occur? perhaps it was due to the SQL being incorrect (before I edited it) - then there would be no rows. So you would hit an error here: `myDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)`

Comment: Then I try to use this one `If CInt(myCommand.ExecuteScalar) = 0 Then` instead still getting error

Comment: Still getting the error on what line??